Azure Logic Apps: ExpressionEvaluationFailed failed
I am trying to create a small onboarding automator using Microsoft Forms and Logic Apps.
I have only added 2 steps so far:
I receive the following error message when I try running it:

Error message:
ExpressionEvaluationFailed
The execution of template action 'For_each' failed: the result of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression '@triggerBody()?['value']' is of type 'Null'. The result must be a valid array.**
Settings:

What could be the issue?
Thanks in advance for the help!
Tried setting it up again, but did not work.
Without the ForEach I receive the following error message:
error message
Code:
 { "type": "ApiConnection", "inputs": { "host": { "connection": { "referenceName": "microsoftforms" } }, "method": "get", "path": "/formapi/api/forms('@{encodeURIComponent('9Ywju8lmBkaYUqnz4XgtY3wbRXZdAfZPsqOnuOYzwdVUMlpPTkFTTzVCU1k3QjNZNThNTklHRjJYTS4u')}')/responses", "queries": { "response_id": "@items('For_each')?['resourceData']?['responseId']" } }, "runAfter": {}, "operationOptions": "DisableAsyncPattern, DisableAutomaticDecompression" }


I believe you should be able to get the response without using the for each loop. If you will see the ouput of the trigger When a new response is Submitted, there is no value parameter in it.

I tried but getting another error message when I want to save the workflow:
Workflow validation failed
The repetition action ForEach referenced by inputs in action 'Get response details' are not defined in the template

Code:
{
"type": "ApiConnection",
"inputs": {
"host": {
"connection": {
"referenceName": "microsoftforms"
}
},
"method": "get",
"path": "/formapi/api/forms('@{encodeURIComponent('9Ywju8lmBkaYUqnz4XgtY3wbRXZdAfZPsqOnuOYzwdVUMlpPTkFTTzVCU1k3QjNZNThNTklHRjJYTS4u')}')/responses",
"queries": {
"response_id": "@items('For_each')?['resourceData']?['responseId']"
}
},
"runAfter": {},
"operationOptions": "DisableAsyncPattern, DisableAutomaticDecompression"
}

change the value to triggerBody()?['resourceData']?['responseId']

I tried changing the response id to that value but it says "Enter a valid integer".
I tried editing it via the "Logic app code view", but if I save it, I cannot run it, says "Invalid parameters".

please check my answer. You need to enable Split on in the trigger if it is not enabled

You should be able to get the response details without using the for each loop as well.
I am using the below workflow-

Please make sure, you have enabled Split on and selected the given value from the dropdown as shown below.


Code-
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Get_response_details": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['microsoftforms']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/formapi/api/forms('@{encodeURIComponent('v4j5cvGGr*************FBGNVBISy4u')}')/responses",
                    "queries": {
                        "response_id": "@triggerBody()?['resourceData']?['responseId']"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_new_response_is_submitted": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "eventType": "responseAdded",
                        "notificationUrl": "@{listCallbackUrl()}",
                        "source": "ms-connector"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['microsoftforms']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "/formapi/api/forms/@{encodeURIComponent('v4j5cvGGr0GRqy1*************GNVBISy4u')}/webhooks"
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerBody()?['value']",
                "type": "ApiConnectionWebhook"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "microsoftforms": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/b83c*********074c23f/resourceGroups/********/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/microsoftforms",
                    "connectionName": "microsoftforms",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/b83************4c23f/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/microsoftforms"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


This workflow will trigger, every time a response is submitted in Microsoft forms. If you will see the output of When a new response is submitted trigger, there is no value parameter in it. Due to this, you are getting the value of triggerBody()?['value'] as null.



In Get response details action, it is giving you result based on the value of responseId.



Thanks for the detailed answer!
I have set up like this, however, when I try running the workflow in the designer I get the following error message:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getResponseHeader').

You shouldn't manually trigger it. This workflow will automatically trigger when there will be any response submitted to that particular form. Have you tried it?

Thanks for your help, I have tested it and it indeed works!
